# Parsing a string to server in c

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string into floating and doubles. The main issue seems to be in sscanf as serveViewer is a default given function and the task only requires me to write a parsing(Sscanf) for the string.

This is my current code and it doesn't seem to be functioning properly but I can't figure out what's wrong with my parsing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
void routeRequest(int socket, char requestBuffer[REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE]) {
int z = 0;
double x = 0, y = 0;
// This is the format of the requestBuffer
char *format = "GET /mandelbrot/2/%d/%lf/%lf/tile.bmp HTTP/1.1";

// Attempts to scan in z, x, and y from requestBuffer - this will
// work correctly if the user enters in a URL with the structure
// http://localhost:1511/mandelbrot/2/z/x/y/tile.bmp
if (sscanf (requestBuffer, format, &z, &x, &y) == 3) {
    serveImage (socket, x, y, z);

    // If sscanf was not successful (i.e. if the values are invalid,
    // such as 'abc' or the user typed in http://localhost:1511), 
    // the code will automatically deliver the viewer instead.
} else {
    printf("Request did not contain (valid) z, x, or y values.\n"
           "Delivering the Mandelbrot viewer instead...\n");
    serveViewer (socket);
}
}
```

Comment: "*it doesn't seem to be functioning properly*" please, what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Variable names like `x`, `y`, `z`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: the compiler should be warning you about using a reference to the format string rather than the actual format string in the call to `sscanf()`  This is because using a reference to the format string is a security hole

Comment: If you think the string isn't being "parsed" correctly, you should use a debugger to see what the values of x, y and z are after the call to sscanf. If you don't know how to use a debugger, this would be a good opportunity to learn, but you could at least print out the values. If you have done one of those things, it would have been a good idea to include that information in your question, since most of us here cannot read minds.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say what the issue is when you say *"it doesn't seem to be functioning properly"*

Here is the code I used to test your function:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE 450

void routeRequest(int socket, char requestBuffer[REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE]) {
    int z = 0;
    double x = 0, y = 0;
// This is the format of the requestBuffer
    char *format = "GET /mandelbrot/2/%d/%lf/%lf/tile.bmp HTTP/1.1";

// Attempts to scan in z, x, and y from requestBuffer - this will
// work correctly if the user enters in a URL with the structure
// http://localhost:1511/mandelbrot/2/z/x/y/tile.bmp
    if (sscanf (requestBuffer, format, &z, &x, &y) == 3) {
        //serveImage (socket, x, y, z);

        printf("Values received: %d %lf %lf\n", z, x, y);

        // If sscanf was not successful (i.e. if the values are invalid,
        // such as 'abc' or the user typed in http://localhost:1511),
        // the code will automatically deliver the viewer instead.
    } else {
        printf("Request did not contain (valid) z, x, or y values.\n"
               "Delivering the Mandelbrot viewer instead...\n");
        //serveViewer (socket);
    }
}

void main()
{
    char buffer1[REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE] = "GET /mandelbrot/2/4/0.5/0.6/tile.bmp HTTP/1.1";
    routeRequest(1, buffer1);

    char buffer2[REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE] = "GET /mandelbrot/2/5/5.5/6.782378/tile.bmp HTTP/1.1";
    routeRequest(1, buffer2);

    char buffer3[REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE] = "GET /mandelbrot/2/76554/188.59/698797/tile.bmp HTTP/1.1";
    routeRequest(1, buffer3);
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
Values received: 4 0.500000 0.600000
Values received: 5 5.500000 6.782378
Values received: 76554 188.590000 698797.000000
```

Please elaborate the question so that I can modify my answer accordingly. It would be best if you could organize the question as:
Problem:
Input:
Output:
Expected Output: